# Expected @param tag for 'x'

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

```
/**
 * Checks whether the given coordinates are with the borders of the map
 *
 * @param x x-coordinate to be checked.
 * @param y y-coordinate to be checked.
 * @param shouldSucceed The expected outcome.
 */
public void testBorders(int x, int y, boolean shouldSucceed) {
```

When generating a checkstyle report with maven, it says

> Warning   javadoc JavadocMethod   Expected @param tag for 'x'.

for all variables, does anybody know what I am doing wrong or why maven is telling me the tag isn't present?

Comment: do you have a local variable with the same name(`x`) in the class with this method? Also could you share the checkstyle configuration you are using.

Comment: My checkstyle file is https://pastebin.com/w9iN4JMN
And the class does not contain any other variables which share the same name, I also get the checkstyle errors for the other variables.

Comment: could you try and change the scope of JavaDocMethod to public in the xml and re run the checks.

Comment: Also the conventions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) reads to avoid using one character variable names. So its better to provide some meaningful names to the variables x and y in your case as well.

Comment: Changed the scope of the checkstyle.xml and changed the names of the variables, still getting the same error though.

Comment: If I run Checkstyle 7.7 from IDEA on the code snippet you gave I cannot reproduce the warning.

Comment: Strange, I'll ask my partner if he can checkstyle as well on the snippet

Comment: I cannot reproduce as well. Please make sure you have the correct file in the correct folder and for the correct line. Please also try to reproduce the issue outside maven with a small sample and give it to us. See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/report_issue.html#How_to_report_a_bug .